# eclipse locks jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, m2e, eclipse-indigo

I have a maven project in `eclipse indigo` with `m2e 1.2.0.20120903-1050` maven plugin. That project contains maven `system` dependencies and these jar files are checked into git repository.

That is all fine until I need to switch to another branch which has changes in `system` dependencies. Git can not update contents as file is locked.

That seems that eclipse on its own or on behalf of m2e locked jar libraries. I tried closing project but that does not help, in order to release lock I have to restart eclipse.

That is rather cumbersome. Are there any trick to release lock without restarting eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

### Windows

You can manualy use `handle.exe` from http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

1. `handle.exe .jar` gives you a list by handle-id and process-id of all `jar's`.
2. `handle.exe -c <handle-id> -p <process-id>` kills the Handle, maybe a exception will be thrown, if so, fill a *bug-report* to Eclipse's *bug-report-system* please to let us know about dead-locks.

### EDIT:

It is important to execute the command using Administrator rights (Thanks to Paulo Merson).

Comment: I tried handle. It was useful to confirm that Eclipse is indeed the process keeping the lock. However, `handle -c <handle-id> -p <pid>` did not work. It asked for confirmation, but at the end the message was "Error closing handle: invalid identifier".

Comment: @PauloMerson hm, I am wondering what identifier is meant. Maybe the file-lock-identifier. A invalid identifier is a identifier who does not point to a file-lock anymore. Maybe the lock is gone. Could you check if the handle-id changes rapidly?

Comment: I first called `handle C:\<path>\myjar.jar`. The output showed `eclipse.exe        pid: 20272  type: File          1314: C:\<path>\myjar.jar`. There's no clear indication of what is the handle id, but by exclusion I assumed it is `1314`. So I tried `handle -c 1314 -p 20272`, got a confirmation question `Close handle 1314 in eclipse.exe (PID 20272)? (y/n)`, answered yes, but got `Error closing handle: The handle is invalid`.

Comment: This is very interesting and your assumptation seems correct. 1314 is very low. The pid meant to be periodicaly increased but the value is pretty low. I dont think anymore the handle-id changes rapidly. Another reason might be the windows rights. Can you execute the command-line as an administrator?

Comment: BINGO! When I open the command-line as administrator, `handle` closes the handle. (Worth a note in your answer if you will.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with Windows. It's a problem with something Eclipse is doing. It's keeping the file open for the duration of the Eclipse runtime. That is a horrible practice.

Comment: I am experiencing this also. I have to close Eclipse to do an ant build, this is a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the [Sysinternals Suite from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/) and make use of the **handle.exe** or **procexp.exe** program to find which program has a handle on the jar. It appears to be safe to close the handle in Eclipse (I've not noticed any side-effects).

It's documented on the sysinternals site how to use [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) and for procexp.exe use the *Find* -> *Find Handle or DLL* menu option. Type the name of the locked jar file, then select the locking process in the sub-window. In the main window it should show a handle to the file within a process, you can check the process is what you think it is, then right click the handle and choose *Close Handle*.

You should run both these tasks with administrator rights.

There are other guides also available on the net:

- http://www.timstall.com/2009/02/killing-file-handles-but-not-process.html

Answer (score 1):

No.  If the files are open, git cannot remove them.  This is a windows thing.

I would suggest you instead install them in your local repository, instead of dealing with system scope,

Comment: Jar files are used in legacy ant build scripts, so I can not make changes to them. I would like somehow tell eclipse to release locks without restarting :)

Comment: Try closing the projects. In your situation I would not switch branches in the same workspace but have a separate workspace for each branch.

Comment: Closing does not help, I tried. I moved to one workspace for many branches deliberately as it simplifies switching among different project versions. That would be too much workspaces if I created it for each branch made.

Comment: Currently I have 3 branches I work with and about 10 branches that I use from time to time.

Comment: Our branches vary wildly - I have found that Eclipse does not cope well with varying submodules in the branches - so I simply have a workspace pr branch.  With as few as you have there, I would do the same if I were you.  Maven is simply not yet a first class citizen of Eclipse and all the handwaving done by m2e does not cover this completely.  That said, I would suspect your ant tasks for this - do you run all maven and ant tasks in a forked jvm?

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with this as well. It turns out this is caused by Windows indexing files. I am using Windows 7. I went to the control panel and selected Indexing options. I made sure to remove any folder that my code was located in. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues using RAD(eclipse) at work. In my case it happens when decompiling with the JD-Eclipse (1.0.0) plugin. I don't have issues when installing the latest Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) and JD-Eclipse (1.0.0). I suspect the underlying version of eclipse (4.2.1) in the version of RAD at work are incompatible with JD-Eclipse (1.0.0).